# Select current outlined code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

If I have several outlines is there a way to SELECT the one containing the cursor?

In the SQL Example(my actual code is much more complicated!) below I like to select the current outline and then execute it, without bothering the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I understand it correctly, the shortcut `Ctrl + M, Ctrl + M` should do it.

Look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td6a5x4s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for further Outlining shortcuts.

Comment: @Adrian Yes, what's the problem?

Comment: I wanted to SELECT/HIGHLIGHT the outline's content, then SHIFT+CONTROL+E would execute it, I have a bunch of queries in one SQL file. Although COLLAPSE,HOME,SHIFT+END is closest I think i'm going to get without writing an extension....used to able to write macros to do this in VS < 13 :-(